# Can you get any data from the Binance API without authentification?

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I am using the Binance Futures API. I am using wrapper library python-binance.

I understand you won't be able to get personal data without authentication, but is there any data available publicly?

Where is this specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You can initialize `Client()` without any api key or secret ([documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=Client#module-binance.client)):

```py
import binance

client = binance.Client()
r = client.get_historical_klines('ETHBTC', client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, '1-Dec-2017', '1-Dec-2017')
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[[1512086400000, '0.04368400', '0.04432900', '0.04227500', '0.04239700', '83006.12100000', 1512172799999, '3596.96984104', 76803, '40633.85900000', '1761.03625471', '269562.18933427']]
```

---

If you don't want to use the `python-binance` wrapper, you can call the Binance API directly.

Check out the [Binance API documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#change-log). You can check the different security types and its authentication requirements [here](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#endpoint-security-type).

For example, you can retreive kline/candlestick data without authentication:

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=15m"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

The [limits](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#general-api-information) for the Binance API are tracked per IP address, and in every endpoint documentation, there is a weight attached to that call.